# chromedriver.exe has stopped working in selenium for latest chrome version 67 but works fine in 57 version

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

chromedriver.exe has stopped working. The message is getting displayed once the URL gets loaded and the page is waiting to get entered with user id and password.
In the latest version of chrome browser 67 and chromedriver version 2.38 when running in selenium with java, but works fine in an older version of chrome browser 57 and driver version 2.28.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the help section on how to write a question...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Initially selenium code was designed to run in chrome version 57 and now when the version is getting updated to 66 , its show that error ,from the selenium code the url is getting loaded , but not getting signed in. i tired to update the chrome driver.exe version to latest ,but not working